# How to change the cell height of inner table view cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a dynamic table view inside a static table view. I am not able to change the cell height according to the cell content. I have tried various methods like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (ProfileData.profileViewType == .favourite) {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell", for: indexPath) as? ProfileCell {  // gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS in SimpleCheckbox library
            cell.favouritesTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.favouritesTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
            print(cell.favouritesTitleLabel.text)
            let height = cell.favouritesTitleLabel.text!.height(withConstrainedWidth: cell.frame.width - 64, font: UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 17.0)!)
            print(height + 16)
            return height + 16
        }
    }
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I have tried setting `UITableView.automaticDiemension`, but it is not adjusting to the text view. It is getting larger. If I try `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell") as! ProfileCell` I am getting only the contents of two cells and rest are not getting the text value.

The current UI screenshot is:
[UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL0d4.png)

I have set the following table view config in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
profileTableView = ProfileSectionTableView()
profileTableView.profileDelegate = self
profileSectionTableView.delegate = profileTableView
profileSectionTableView.dataSource = profileTableView
profileSectionTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
profileSectionTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Comment: Why you're created dynamic tableview in static tableview?

Comment: That is how I had to structure the UI. I have three tab like images which when clicked should update the table view.

Comment: This is the wrong way to implement can you add UI Screenshots so I can tell you how to implement?

Comment: To confirm, have you set _both_ `.estimatedRowHeight = 60` and `rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`? Both are needed for cells to resize dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I have added. I have updated the question with more details and UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`,you must set `cellData` again but get data with cell. Then calculate the height.